# When to Use vm. or this. in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a little confused on when to use the "this" word in vue.js. For example, in the code below everywhere I use "vm" instead of "this" the code does not work.

I have also seen some examples using "self", however I am not a javascript guru and this is really confusing.

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            tickets: [],
            top: 100,
            search: '',
            showAdd: false,
         },
        mounted: function () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                console.log('mounted');
                this.GetTickets(100);
            })
        },
        methods: {
            GetTickets: function (top) {
                axios.get('/api/Tickets', {
                    params: {
                        Top: top
                    }
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        vm.tickets = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
            ClearTicket: function () {
                var t = {
                    "ticketSubject": '',
                    "contactName": '',
                    "createdAt": moment()
                }
                vm.ticket = t;
                vm.showAdd = !vm.showAdd;
            },
            AddTicket: function () {
                //vm.tickets.unshift(vm.ticket);
                axios.post('/api/Tickets', vm.ticket)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        vm.GetTickets(100);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                vm.showAdd = false;

            }
        },

    })
```

Comment: I think it would help to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) about the `this` keyword and functions/callbacks.  Then, understand that `this` in Vue methods [points to the Vue instance](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html).

Answer (score 54):

Typically, inside methods, or computed properties or lifecycle handlers in Vue, you will use `this` to refer the component to which the method/computed/handler is attached. `this` refers to the context in which the function is currently executing.

Where you get into trouble using `this` is when a new function is declared in the context of the current function, as happens when you write a callback to a promise (`axios.post`, `axios.get`). Consider this code:

```
AddTicket: function () {
  // "this", on this line, refers to the Vue
  // and you can safely use "this" to get any of the
  // data properties of the Vue
    axios.post('/api/Tickets', ...)
      .then(function (response) {
        // "this" HERE, does NOT refer to the Vue!!
        // The reason why explained below              
      })
}
```

In the above code, the first comment could be replaced with code that uses `this` to get data properties or call methods of the Vue (`this.tickets`). The second comment, however is *inside* a new function context, and `this` will NOT refer to the Vue. This is because in Javascript when you declare a new function using the `function() {}` syntax, that function has its own function context which is *different* from the function in which it is declared.

There are several ways to deal with this in Javascript. The most common these days are to either use a closure to capture the correct `this`, or to use an arrow function. Consider this code:

```
AddTicket: function () {
  // As before, "this" here is the Vue
    axios.post('/api/Tickets', ...)
      .then((response) => {
        // "this" HERE is ALSO the Vue
      })
}
```

Note that in this example, the callback is defined using an arrow function (`() => {}`). Arrow functions do NOT create their own function context and use the context in which they are declared. This is also known as having a lexical scope.

The other most common workaround is using a closure.

```
AddTicket: function () {
  const self = this // Here we save a reference to the "this" we want
    axios.post('/api/Tickets', ...)
      .then(function(response){
        // and HERE, even though the context has changed, and we can't use
        // "this", we can use the reference we declared (self) which *is*
        // pointing to the Vue
        self.tickets = response
      })
}
```

Finally, you can use the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a function with a specific `this`, though this is not as common these days with arrow functions available.

```
AddTicket: function () {
    axios.post('/api/Tickets', ...)
      .then(function(response){
        this.tickets = response
      }.bind(this)) // NOTE the ".bind(this)" added to the end of the function here
}
```

In almost no case, should you really be doing what you do in your question, which is save a reference to the Vue in the variable `vm` and use that variable *inside* the Vue object itself. That's a bad practice.

In any case, how to use the correct `this` is covered in detail in numerous posts [throughout the internet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) as well.

Finally, here is the code from the question revised such that `this` *should* be used correctly.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tickets: [],
    top: 100,
    search: '',
    showAdd: false,
    ticket: null
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // there is no need for $nextTick here
    this.GetTickets(100)
  },
  methods: {
    GetTickets: function (top) {
      axios.get('/api/Tickets', { params: { Top: top }})
        .then(response => this.tickets = response.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
    ClearTicket: function () {
      var t = {
        "ticketSubject": '',
        "contactName": '',
        "createdAt": moment()
      }
      this.ticket = t;
      this.showAdd = !this.showAdd;
    },
    AddTicket: function () {
      axios.post('/api/Tickets', this.ticket)
        .then(() => this.GetTickets(100))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

      this.showAdd = false;
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Very good post! Maybe add a note about `fn.bind(this)` to complete your explanation?

Answer (score 6):

In the end, it is simple. Until you do not fully understand how it works, just follow these simple rules:

Use `this` everywhere in Vue object, and use its reference identifier outside:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  // Use "this" inside
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    something: true
  },
  created: function () {
    this.something = false // like here
  }
})

// Here, outside, use reference iditentifier,
// as you have no other choice
vm.something = null
```

Never use reference name inside the referenced object itself. Outside the Vue object you have no other choice, you just must use the reference name.

Inside Vue, `this` content may vary. And will. It is just another object, automatically created within each function/object. So you need this second rule: before you dive to nested, second level function, save `this` to reference/variable. Why:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    something: true
  },
  created: function () {
    // You are in first level function,
    // you can use "this"
    axios.get('/uri').then(function () {
      // Here you are in nested, second level
      // function. It will have own "this" object
      this.something = false // no error here but...
      // You did not changed "something" value in data object,
      // you just created new property also called "something",
      // but in this nested "this" object.
    })
  }
})
```

As mentioned above, every function obtains it's own `this` object. So, with 'this.something = false' you just created new property 'something' in 'this' object in nested, second level function, instead of changing 'this' in first level function. In other words, in nested function you lost reference to previous `this` from first level function, as it's content was overwrited with newly created content in process of nested function creation. So, if you need to use `this` object form first level function in nested function, just save it under another name, which will be not overwrited:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    something: true
  },
  created: function () {
    var anyName = this // Save reference to this under another name
    axios.get('/uri').then(function () {
      this.something = false // no error here, but you are still creating new property
      anyName.something = false // NOW you are really changing "something" value in data
    })
  }
})
```

As you can see, you can save it under any name. But follow the convenience and name it as `self`. Not `vm`, as this name can confuse you again, whether it will collide with `var vm = new Vue()`, or not. It will not, but doesn't confuse yourself and just name it as `self`.

Does not experiment with arrow functions, do not use bind. Just follow this simple rules. Later, you will be more experienced, you can (and should) use them, but for now, enjoy the coding, not debugging :)

Comment: Another great post! Thanks for all the help.