# vm.attribute vs. this.attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This may be a simple question but I feel like I need some clarification... I have vuejs running on a single page of my site. The vm app is running in the footer script of the page (I am not using an app.js file or templates/components etc.)

Inside one of my vue methods, this works fine:

```
newContainer(){
   this.attribute = 'value'; //this works!
}
```

I am also using axios and inside its functions I have to do this instead:

```
axios.post('my/route', {
        attribute: this.attribute //this works
    }).then(function (response) {
        vm.attribute = 'value'; //this works
        this.attribute = 'value'; //this does not work
    });
```

I realise this is probably due to it being in a function that `this.attribute` does not work while `vm.attribute` does work. However... why is this and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: print out "this" and you will see that you're in a different scope

Comment: Add `let vm = this` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148363/when-to-use-vm-or-this-in-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following after code

```js
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                title:"Form Register",
                formdata:{},
                message:"",
                success:0,
            }
        },
        methods:{
           register(){
                this.axios.post("http://localhost:8888/form-register",this.formdata).then((response) => {
                       console.log(response);
                       if(response.data.success>0){
                           this.message="You register success";
                           this.success=response.data.success;
                       }
                       else{
                           this.message="Register to failed";
                           this.success=response.data.success;
                       }
                  });
                    
            },
 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use arrow functions like `() => {...}` it binds current context. And `this` will point to right context. So if you use it instead of `function() {...}` where context is not binded it will work. Like

`.then(response => {this.attribute = 'value'}`

Comment: Thanks, but does this only work if you have a single value to set, or function to run etc.

Comment: @AdamLambert not sure I understand the question, may you clearify it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really common stumbling block for developers.  The reason is that inside an axios function your code out of scope of the object containing the axios method call.  This can more easily be see if you rewrite this block of code to be like the one below it:

```
 var vm = {
      function doWork(){
        axios.post('my/route', {
              attribute: this.attribute //this works
        }).then(function (response) {
              vm.attribute = 'value'; //this works
              this.attribute = 'value'; //this does not work
         });
      }
 }
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
 var vm = {
      function doWork(){
          axios.post('my/route', {
                attribute: this.attribute //this works
           }).then(followOnWork(response));
      }
 }

 function followOnWork(response){
      vm.attribute = 'value'; //this works
      this.attribute = 'value'; //this does not work
 }
```

As you can see in this refactored code, `followOnWork` is running totally independently of the `vm` object.  So any use of a `this` variable in `followOnWork` isn't going to relate to the `vm` object.  Where as `vm` is the actual name of the object and once the object is created it can be accessed from *anywhere* via the `vm` variable.

You can get around this "out of scope" problem by using an arrow function (as mentioned by @MakarovSergey) if ES6 is an option for you.