# How to use router push inside a VueJs component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a navbar component, I need to redirect to the login component inside a logout method declared at navbar.

I tried: `this.$router.push({name:'MyLogin'});`

But I see the error:

> vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined
> at eval (main.js?56d7:68)

How can I use router push inside a component?

Or how can I inside this component make access to the router.

**EDIT :**

At the file: **/src/router.js** I have the Login route:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginView
    },
```

And at the file: **/src/components/Navibar.vue** I have the doLogout method:

```
methods: {
    doLogout(){ 
    this.$router.push({name:'Login'}); 
}
```

Being new to Vue js I tried this:

```
doLogout(){
   const router = new router({
    routes: [
              { 
                path: '/login', 
                name: 'Login', 
                component: LoginView 
              }               
        ]
  })
 this.$router.push({name:'Login'});
```

}

I see the error message:

> doLogout catch ReferenceError: LoginView is not defined at eval (VM2993 NaviBar.vue:324)

So I tried to add the component:

```
Vue.component('LoginView', require('Login.vue'));
```

Which gives me the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Login.vue'

Maybe I am doing the wrong steps?

Which is the correct way to enable `this.$router.push()` inside one component redirecting to another component?

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148363/when-to-use-vm-or-this-in-vue-js/47148828#47148828

Comment: Something is wrong with your component since `this` is undefined.  We can't tell from that one line.  What does the rest of the component look like?

Comment: Add the whole function over here in which you are doing push in router.

Comment: The login route is defined this way :

Comment: export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginView
    },

Comment: Login.vue and NaviBar.vue are both at the components directory

Comment: Hi, @Riddhi i edit the post showing my steps to try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring as below :

At the file: /src/router.js

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginView
    },
export default router
```

The router variable declared is accessible over all vue components.

Hence at the file: /src/components/Navibar.vue doLogout method :

```
methods: {
    doLogout(){ 
    this.$router.push({name:'Login'}); 
}
```

Comment: It will be : const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginView
    }
})

export default router  ??

Comment: thank´s @Riddhi, now debuging i see the entire router object, this is at the navbar component, just don´t know why it stays on the same page, it does not redirect.