# How to change data in Vue JS dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue JS as my frontend. I have encountered a problem.

This is my component data -

```
data: () => ({
        email: "",
        showError : false
    }),
```

And this is the html -

```
<div v-show='showError' class='errorBox'>
    <p>Error</p>
</div>
```

I am not able to change the showError in the data dynamically. I am writing the code to change the value something like this but it does not change and does not show any error in the console -

```
axios.get('/accounts/passwordresetpage_ajax_validation/' + '?email=' + email.value)
.then(function (res) {
                        if (res.data.email_does_not_exists) {
                            return this.showError = true
                        } else {
                        document.querySelector('form').submit()
                            
                        }
                    });
```

This piece of code is inside a component method. Someone please help

Answer (score 1):

like @punund said, `this` here does not reference the component to which the data property is attached. The context in which you are using the `this` keyword is in the callback. There are a couple of things you can do. You can use a variable to save a reference to `this`

```js
const self = this;
axios.get('/accounts/passwordresetpage_ajax_validation/' + '?email=' + email.value)
  .then(function (res) {
    if (res.data.email_does_not_exists) {
      self.showError = true
    } else {
      document.querySelector('form').submit()
    }
  });
```

You can also use the `bind` method to return a function that has the context of the vue component

```js
axios.get('/accounts/passwordresetpage_ajax_validation/' + '?email=' + email.value)
  .then(function (res) {
    if (res.data.email_does_not_exists) {
      this.showError = true
    } else {
      document.querySelector('form').submit()
    }
  }.bind(this)
  );
```

My personal favourite way, and the cleanest way to get the `this` keyword to reference the vue component is to use the ES2015 arrow function

```js
 axios.get('/accounts/passwordresetpage_ajax_validation/' + '?email=' + email.value)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.data.email_does_not_exists) {
          this.showError = true
    } else {
      document.querySelector('form').submit()
    }
  });
```

If you want to know more, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148363/when-to-use-vm-or-this-in-vue-js) post does an excellent job of explaining it.

Alternatively, if videos are your thing, you can reference this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjJoX9F_F5g) video which does a masterful job of explaining context.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside `.then(function (res)` doesn't point to what you think.  Access `data` directly:

```
axios.get('/accounts/passwordresetpage_ajax_validation/' + '?email=' + email.value)
.then(function (res) {
                        if (res.data.email_does_not_exists) {
                            return data.showError = true
                        } else {
                        document.querySelector('form').submit()
                            
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: How do I do it?